# Why does DllImport require an Identifier?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I'm a little confused.

In the code:

```
[DllImport("library.dll")]
public static extern void function(int x);
```

why is the x required?  Shouldn't the int be enough as this is just a definition and not a declaration?

Comment: Remember, the question for a language is not "Why is my feature missing?" It's "[Why wasn't my feature added](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx)?" This particular feature would require a context-sensitive change to the function declaration parser. (It would have to know what type of function it is declaring.) This complicates the grammar for relatively little benefit.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused.  Why would not having the x mean it wouldn't know what type of function it is declaring?  a void function(int) is a funciton that takes an int and returns nothing.  What does the 'x' add to this?  Certainly it needs 'function', because that's the name of the function to import...

Comment: This means that `DllImport` declarations (parameter names are optional) have to be parsed differently from non-`DllImport` declarations (parameter names are mandatory). This means that the function declaration parser needs to know what kind of declaration it is parsing, which makes this significantly more complicated for relatively little benefit. "I want to add this feature so that it is easier to write less readable code."

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying: when MSFT was extending the language by adding the ability for the *compiler* to interpret DllImports, the new functionality had to perform nearly the same job as was already done by the compiler when interpreting ordinary functions.  Thus, it was easier just to reuse that parser, even though that parser needed a parameter name, than it was to write a new one or modify the original one just so you could not require those parameter names.  It was both the easier coding choice, and had the side effect of encouraging good code documentation practices.

Comment: DllImport was probably part of the compiler from the start. But the basic logic is the same: Why make a complicated parser when a simpler one works just fine? (It also would have hindered C# 4.0 from introducing named argument syntax, since you would have had scenarios where arguments have no name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the C# Syntax, the same goes for methods in interface.

Probably the biggest reason is, that it adds clarity to the code. Parameter name may tells about the expected value in method

Comment: So, no reason, in other words?

Comment: Well, with respect to interfaces, names are useful with optional parameters, Also they add more clarity to the code. The parameter name may specify what kind of values are expected in the function

Comment: Actually, the "reason" is that so the method's implementation can find the parameter ;)  The thing *I* don't understand is why C++ lets you declare prototypes where parameters *don't* need to have names.  Pretty useless, if you ask me ;

Comment: @cwm9: You don't think that code clarity is a good reason?  Have you ever worked with a c++ library that has headers in the form of `void magic(int, int, int, double, double*, char*);`?  I don't know of any technical reasons, but that's good enough for me.

Comment: I think clarity is wonderful... it just seems strange to have it forced upon me.  I'm sure I could come up with dozens of places that could be made syntatically clearer by sprinkling in a few extra unneeded yet required  identifiers...  Making it required makes me wonder why it's there!